# Git on Windows post-receive hook to create bundle

Tags: git

I have a git repo hosted on an apache 2.2 server running as a local service on a windows 2003 server.  I'd like to add a git post-receive hook to have a bundle in the dropbox sync directory updated.  The client pull and push work and I am able to generated the bundle at the windows command line, I am stumbling over how to write and debug the hook's shell script.

As a first stab I created a post-receive file under hooks directory with the contents below, but nothing seems to happen when I push changes to the server

!/bin/sh

git bundle create "C:\Documents and Settings\fkhan\My Documents\Dropbox\git_bundles\cs701.bundle" master --all

When a hook fails are there any logs generated that can be used for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no log file is generated. You can modify your script to log what you want though.

Also, make sure your script is executable.